# Adjust brightness on leaflet map using slider

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I am trying to adjust the brightness of leaflet map using slider. Basically, adjusting the map light to low and high using slider.

Any assistance doing this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Were you looking for something [like this](http://jsbin.com/rekaluf/5/edit?html,css,js,output)?

Add a slider element to the HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="opacity-slider">
```

Here is the JavaScript that handles the slider:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('opacity-slider');
slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var value = Number(e.target.value);
  var opacity = value / 100;
  tileLayer.setOpacity(opacity);
});
```

The code adjusts the opacity of the map's tile layer when the slider is moved.

For the CSS, the background color of the map div element is set to black:

```
#map {
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: FWIW you also have the [Leaflet.OpacityControls](https://github.com/lizardtechblog/Leaflet.OpacityControls) plugin ([demo](http://lizardtechblog.github.io/Leaflet.OpacityControls/))

Comment: Did not know about this, thanks for sharing! Worth posting as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks both of you! Exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: I want to adjust "filter: brightness(1.1);". It's by default css property. Any recommendation how to do it in JS or Angular5?

Comment: Not sure. I recommend creating a new question and adding all the details there so you can get help from more of the community.